# Authentication error when logging into website through BluePrism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am trying to setup a simple RPA application through BluePrism which will login into a website and will perform certain tasks. Now, while logging into the website through BluePrism I am getting Authentication error although the password and username is correct.

Normally, I can login but error is showing while logging through BluePrism. Can anyone please tell why this is happening?

Comment: Likely that the site you're attempting to log into employs a validation script that won't even fire correctly if there hasn't been a keyboard press event in one of the fields. You may want to try utilizing `Global Send Keys` or `Global Send Key Events` to write the username and password. However, without seeing the site or knowing which frameworks/event triggers it utilizes, it'll be impossible to diagnose this problem effectively. Consider adding a bit more clarifying information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for passing credentials (Username & Password)
1. Hard Coded - If you are using hard coded values, please check if values are correct. Sometimes space or any special characters can lead us to error.
2. Credential Manager - If you are passing credentials through credential manager make sure you are using correct variables mapping so that there is no mismatch.
3. Lastly make sure you are using wait stage so that while executing the application it is waiting for values to be pasted or passed before control moving to other screen or other function.

Answer (score -1):

Please check caps lock key of keyboard, when running the process.